# What's the difference between "cdma_shadow" and "shadow" builds in CyanogenMod 7.2

Tags: cyanogenmod, motorola-droid-x

- In 2011, Motorola Droid X was somewhat supported by CyanogenMod 7.1+, and was known under "**cdma_shadow**" tag: http://download.cyanogenmod.com/?device=cdma_shadow&type=nightly

  It had - and still has - only 2 official nightlies builds (the latest from 2011-11-16) and no RCs or stable releases.
- Now, I just found another tag ("**shadow**"): http://download.cyanogenmod.com/?device=shadow&type=nightly

  It has 4 nightly builds (last one 2012-06-17), all 3 RC builds and **a stable build**.
- However, that other "**shadow**" build looks suspiciously wrong to me:

  - Clicking on "Motorola Droid X" from CM device page links to "**cdma_shadow**" (the one with 2 2011 nightlies and no stable releases).
  - To the best of my knowledge, CM7.2 never worked well on Droid X.
  - The tag lacks "cdma" prefix.

Q1: **What is the "shadow" tag?** Is it a new name for Motorola Droid X for CM7.2? Is it non-CDMA version of Droid X? A cdma_shadow port without working CDMA radios?

Q2: How well does this "shadow" stable build support Verizon's Motorola Droid X?

---

A little extra info: I just downloaded the actual "shadow" stable ROM, and "build.prop" file has this:

> ro.build.fingerprint=verizon/shadow_vzw/cdma_shadow/shadow:2.2.1/VZW/23.340:user/ota-rel-keys,release-keys
>   ro.product.model=DROIDX
>   ro.product.brand=verizon
>   ro.product.name=shadow_vzw
>   ro.product.device=cdma_shadow
>   ro.product.board=shadow

... abd further down ...

> # Default network type.
>   # 4 => CDMA / EVDO.
>   ro.telephony.default_network=4
>   ro.com.google.clientid=android-motorola
>   ro.cdma.home.operator.numeric=310004
>   ro.cdma.home.operator.alpha=Verizon

Comment: As a note, I searched a bunch of forums, and only got not-very-official-looking advice, ranging from "shadow is the new cdma_shadow" to "cm7.2 doesn't work on DX unless you use unofficial builds + separate camera fix"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### **EDITED**

[Found the official source](http://www.cyanogenmod.com/blog/cyanogenmod-7-2-0-rc1-is-upon-us) where can be read that the Motorola Droid X build was renamed to shadow:

> Also worthy of note: the new release files have a slightly modified naming-scheme, including the codename instead of the commercial/common name in the filename. So the following is a handy “translation chart” to make sure you don’t mis-identify your device...
>
> ...
>
> shadow -  Motorola Droid X
>
> ...

---

### **Original Answer**

At [cyanogenmod downloads](http://download.cyanogenmod.com/), the build identified by `cdma_shadow` stopped at `cm_shadow_full-154.zip` (*the available links are broken*).

When they were resumed, they've been renamed to `shadow`, being `shadow` the codename for the Droid X.

- **Droid X** formerly known as Droid Xtreme, has the development codename "Shadow".
- **CDMA** Stands for: Code Division Multiple Access. It is the general system used for 3G services.

---

### Related information:

> **CDMA Technology** - CDMA is a wireless technology standard used by Verizon Wireless in all of its phones, and by certain other carriers in the countries listed at [this link](http://businessportals.verizonwireless.com/international/technology/cdma.html).

---

### **Trying further to justify this answer:**

Here's the metadata found at `/META-INF/com/android/metadata` for the [cm-7-20120624-NIGHTLY-shadow.zip](http://get.cm/get/jenkins/3319/cm-7-20120624-NIGHTLY-shadow.zip) where can be seen the reference to the **cdma_shadow**:

```
post-build=verizon/shadow_vzw/cdma_shadow/shadow:2.2.1/VZW/23.340:user/ota-rel-keys,release-keys
post-timestamp=1289194863
pre-device=cdma_shadow
```

[image: Motorola Droid X Shadow Build Download Information]

And yet the information presented on the menu hover effect:

[image: Information on mouseover]

Besides from this, the cyanogenmod documentation, forums and wiki pages reveal no better insight and are mentioned to be outdated. This seams to be the best official justification for the build rename.

Comment: Yeah there's 4G/LTE (currently rolled out in some parts - Scandinavia I believe, there's ongoing dispute on this in the UK and Ireland with proprosal to roll out in the EU but licensing of spectrum issues, currently actively used in USA), GSM is Europe-centric, CDMA.. am not 100% sure which area of globe that is, Asia? IIRC, anyone would know for matter of interest. The reason I pointed this out, asian companies - Samsung/HTC is notorious for bringing out variants of the handsets to match the market, even source is slighly different between GSM, CDMA... :)

Comment: Is there a source for your claim that "they [the builds] have been renamed to shadow"? That is my suspicion, but some sort of confirmation is what I was looking for. I now perfectly well what CDMA and shadow mean, but having similar build names a proof does not make.

Comment: It is not a question of having similar build names, if you place your mouse over the "shadow" link, it appears "Motorola Droid X"! And that's on the official [CyanogenMod Downloads](http://get.cm/) page. Sorry, but besides this "official" information, their documentation, forums and wiki pages don't give much enlightenment to the subject and appear to be outdated.

Comment: Took me awhile to find it, but just edited the answer with the official source (change log for the 
CyanogenMod-7.2.0-RC1), hope it helps.

Comment: @Zuul - YAY! The first link is exactly what I was looking for! +1 and accept!

Answer (score 1):

'Shadow' refers to the base model of the phone, cdma_shadow being the Droid X on Verizon, and the regular shadow is likely the Milestone X, a GSM phone released overseas.

While the software is mostly the same, there is likely some difference in the hardware, almost certainly the phone's radio, and sounds like the camera as well, according to what you've been told.

It's not uncommon for the different phone+network combinations to have different codenames, another examble would be the Samsung Galaxy Nexus, with Verizon's LTE version called "toro", and the later Sprint version called "toroplus"

Comment: Then how do the "build.prop" references to cdma are explained?

Comment: @DVK Good question, but that's not the only anomaly. The build fingerprint shows 2.2

Comment: @RichardBorcsik - I am guessing you consider it an anomaly because 7.2 is supposed to be Gingerbread (2.3) based?

Comment: @DVk Yep, that and because it shows the device name, not a Nexus as it is on all other CM roms. i.e: my ZTE Blade running CM9 has the fingerprint of gGlaxy Nexus